# How do I store data from a dropdown

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to store data from an option, but I'm not sure where I went wrong in the schema or the react code. Is there another I could perhaps do it?
I am getting this error in the console

> POST http://localhost:8080/api/user 500 (Internal Server Error)

#### model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const joi = require('joi');
const { optional } = require('joi');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName:{type: String, required: true},
    lastName:{type: String, required: true},
    email:{type: String, required: true},
    password:{type: String, required: true},
    status:{type: String, enum: ['active', 'inactive'],required : true },
});

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function(){
    const token = jwt.sign({_id:this._id}, process.env.JWTPRIVATEKEY)
    return token
}

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

const validate = (data) => {
    const schema = joi.object({
        firstName:joi.string().required().label("First Name"),
        lastName:joi.string().required().label("Last Name"),
        email: joi.string().email().required().label("Email"),
        password: joi.string().required().label("password"),
        status:joi.string().enum['active', 'inactive'].required().label(" ")

    });
    return schema.validate(data)

}

module.exports = {User, validate}
```

here is my jsx code, It doesn't allow me to create a user while have the dropdown present. Quite new to react.

#### index.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./styles.module.css";


const Signup = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        status: "",
        
    });
    



    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
        setData({ ...data, [input.name]: input.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/user";
            const { data: res } = await axios.post(url, data);
            navigate("/login");
            console.log(res.message);
        } catch (error) {
            if (
                error.response &&
                error.response.status >= 400 &&
                error.response.status <= 500
            ) {
                setError(error.response.data.message);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles.signup_container}>
            <div className={styles.signup_form_container}>
                <div className={styles.left}>
                    <h1>Welcome Back</h1>
                    <Link to="/login">
                        <button type="button" className={styles.white_btn}>
                            Sign in
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.right}>
                    <form className={styles.form_container} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <h1>Create Account</h1>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="First Name"
                            name="firstName"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.firstName}
                            required
                            className={styles.input}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Last Name"
                            name="lastName"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.lastName}
                            required
                            className={styles.input}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            placeholder="Email"
                            name="email"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.email}
                            required
                            className={styles.input}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            name="password"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.password}
                            required
                            className={styles.input}
                        />
                        
                        <select name ="status">
                            <option value="1">active</option>
                            <option  value="2">inactive</option>
                        </select>
                        
                        

                        
                        {error && <div className={styles.error_msg}>{error}</div>}
                        <button type="submit" className={styles.green_btn}>
                            Sign Up
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Signup;
```

Comment: The error is on server, can you show me the data you send to backend?

Comment: When you send the data, look at network, put when say "payload", those are the information you send it

Comment: Here it is 
{firstName: "Testname", lastName: "testsurname", email: "testemail@test.com", password: "Password123#",…}
email: "testemail@test.com"
firstName: "Testname"
lastName: "testsurname"
password: "Password123#"
status: ""

Comment: Status is empty, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you need is a state to store the data and event handler to handle the changes. Like so:

```
const MyComponet = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useSate("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      const activeStatus = e.target.value;
      setActive(activeStatus) 
  } 

   return (
     <select onChange={handleChange} >
       <option value="1" >active</option>
       <option value="2" >inactive</option>
     </select>
)}
```

This will allow you to access the `active` value which you can use in a post request.

Comment: Does not work, returns POST http://localhost:8080/api/user 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Then that usually means that the object (data) your trying to post its not what your backend expects. You can console.log the data you are trying to post and check whether it's the kind of data the backed expects, the keys and values of the posted data should be similer to your fields and datatype they expect.